# audio comparison

Tags: .net, php, javascript, c, actionscript

How to compare two audio files to see the difference of them

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in finding out if two audio files sound the same instead of comparing them on a bit level, then the term you are looking for is Acoustic fingerprinting.

There is a good [Wikipedia article on acoustic fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) explaining the process and it includes a whole host of resources, including a few free and open projects.

> An acoustic fingerprint is a condensed
>   digital summary, deterministically
>   generated from an audio signal, that
>   can be used to identify an audio
>   sample or quickly locate similar items
>   in an audio database.

Answer (score 2):

Load audio files with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and you will see differences between audio signals:
[image]

Also in audacity you can do Frequency analysis of signals and compare spectrum of those two signals (menu - Analyze/Plot Spectrum...). You will get something like that:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Existing app :

http://technofriends.in/2009/03/06/audio-files-audio-comparer-helps-you-compare-audio-files/

> Audio Comparer is a Windows desktop
>   application for MP3, MP2, MP1, WMA,
>   AIF, WAV and OGG audio files
>   comparison. The program’s main goal is
>   to find duplicate audio files and sort
>   them in whatever way you want.

But maybe it's code libraries you are after?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to determine whether the two files are different, take an MD5 hash of the file data from each file and if the hashes are the same, the files are the same.

Comment: The only problem here is if the formats are different; two songs in different formats will have totally different hashes. A way around this is to decode it into raw data (.WAV) first. Another issue might be that the hashes are very similar, but not _exact_. There must be algorithms to see how well strings match though? +1 for method. A program called MusicBrainz Picard uses this technique.